# Fix 3rd party library code initialization of a class member function reference parameter with a constant

Tags: c++, icc

When compiling a 3rd party library, I get "error: initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue". The error is occurring in a C++ Class definition in this declaration of a member function:

```
bool intersectsHierarchy(ON_Ray& ray, std::list<BVNode<ON_BoundingBox>*>& results = 0);
```

Based on information I found on the web, I tried to make the initialized parameter be const, as follows:

```
bool intersectsHierarchy(ON_Ray& ray, const std::list<BVNode<ON_BoundingBox>*>& results = 0);
```

But that just causes another compilation error.

Any ideas how to best fix this and get my library to compile?

Comment: Get rid of the `= 0` part in the first example?  Is this your code or someone else?

Comment: This is 3rd party library code, so someone else's. I'm concerned if I get rid of the 0 initialization value, I'll create a bug.

Comment: `0` and `std::list<BVNode<ON_BoundingBox>*>` are different types, and the latter is not constructible from the former (except when *explicitly* invoking a compatible c'tor). This is a bug that no compliant compiler should know how to translate anyway.

Comment: Anything that's relying on that default is broken

Comment: I would suggest getting a different library then.  If they have code like that then there is bound to be other issues.

Comment: In [this header file](http://diyhpl.us/~bryan/irc/brlcad/include/brep.h), the `= 0` jas been removed, perhaps you're using an old version?

Comment: These are some good observations. So are you saying it should be fine to just drop the default initialization value, since it's not the right type, anyway?

Comment: @NathanOliver, getting another library simply isn't an option.

Comment: It's definitely not the right type - hence the compiler error. Instead of editing the file, perhaps you should upgrade. I see the latest version is [7.24.2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/brlcad/files/BRL-CAD%20for%20Linux/) - what version are you running?

Comment: I just downloaded the [source for 7.24.2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/brlcad/files/BRL-CAD%20Source/7.24.2/) and the signature has been fixed. `./include/brep.h:964:    bool intersectsHierarchy(ON_Ray& ray, std::list<BVNode<ON_BoundingBox>*>& results);`

Comment: @SteveLorimer, thanks for pointing out the change in later versions. I made the change in the header for the version I'm using and it fixed the compilation error problem. The reason we haven't yet updated to the latest version, is because we're linking to the static library libbrlcad.a and the new build process no longer produces that library, no matter what configuration settings I've tried. Any ideas how to handle that?

Comment: There are a bunch of prebuilt downloads on the site - are you sure you can't get the library from there? Otherwise you could build from source. I don't know what your build process is, so I can't be more helpful I'm afraid

Answer (score -1, accepted):

remove the  `= 0` part -

1. You cannot assign 0 to a list
2. You can only pass a variable by reference not a `const` value

Comment: *"You can only pass a variable by reference not a const value"* - You can very well bind a reference to an integer literal. You cannot bind an lvalue reference to a constant, but it's irrelevant, whether this constant is an integer literal, or a const variable.